# How to use value after "as" in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my SQL request for a PostgreSQL datatable

```
select main_bundle_statuses.status from (
    select main_bundle.status,
    row_number() over
    (partition by main_bundle.client_id order by main_bundle.created desc)
    as rnum
    from bundle main_bundle
    join config_dependence cd on cd.main_config_id = main_bundle.config_bundle_id
    where cd.dependent_config_id = b.config_bundle_id
    and main_bundle.client_id = b.client_id) main_bundle_statuses
where main_bundle_statuses.rnum = 1) as main_bundle_status,
```

I need to check null value of main_bundle_status, as a second column. I tried to write this:

```
(case
when main_bundle_status is null then true
else false
end) as dependent
```

But I got an error. How can I check the value - is it null or not, and return it as dependent?

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  `b`, for instance, is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `where` in the *outer* query:

```
select . . . 
from ( . . . ) main_bundle_status
where main_bundle_statuses.rnum = 1;
```

Your `join` conditions look all messed up.  `DISTINCT ON` is a better alternative.  I am guessing something like this:

```
select distinct on (b.client_id) b.status,
from bundle b join
     config_dependence cd
     on cd.main_config_id = b.config_bundle_id and
        cd.dependent_config_id = b.dependent_config_bundle_id and
        cd.client_id = b.client_id
order by b.client_id, b.created desc
```

Comment: I need to check a value of main_bundle_status anyway, because I will use it after this part of query

Comment: @МаксимРыбалкин . . . I don't understand your comment.  You can add that condition to a where.  This answers the question you have asked here; if you have a different question, ask a new question with appropriate explanation, sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

main_bundle_status is not a field you can check, is an alias of a subquery that contains another subquery, and i think you missed a '(' at the begining.

You have two options:
- store its value in a temportary table and then check it with the CASE WHEN in a second query

- in the CASE WHEN instead of main_bundle_status write all the subquery, it will be like:

  ```
  (select main_bundle_statuses.status from (
  select main_bundle.status,
  row_number() over
  (partition by main_bundle.client_id order by main_bundle.created desc)
  as rnum
  from bundle main_bundle
  join config_dependence cd on cd.main_config_id =main_bundle.config_bundle_id
  where cd.dependent_config_id = b.config_bundle_id
  and main_bundle.client_id = b.client_id) main_bundle_statuses
  where main_bundle_statuses.rnum = 1) as main_bundle_status,
  CASE WHEN (select main_bundle_statuses.status from (
  select main_bundle.status,
  row_number() over
  (partition by main_bundle.client_id order by main_bundle.created desc)
  as rnum
  from bundle main_bundle
  join config_dependence cd on cd.main_config_id =main_bundle.config_bundle_id
  where cd.dependent_config_id = b.config_bundle_id
  and main_bundle.client_id = b.client_id) main_bundle_statuses
  where main_bundle_statuses.rnum = 1) is null then true else false end as dependent
  ```

Since there's a comma at the end I think this is part of a bigger query and, as stated by @GordonLinoff, it's already a bit confusing.
I suggest the temporary table solution.